# Show content from local drive into browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is my code for fetching files from F drive while my project save in E drive. I have to show my image file in browser which are stored in F drive. Variable "img" contain path of image as "F:\Test\foldername\aa.jpg".

```
foreach (string img in Model.SImages)
{
    if (img != null)
    {
        string ss = img.Substring(img.LastIndexOf("Imagery/") + 8);
   <div style="width:100px;height:185px;display:inline-block;margin:10px 5px; vertical-align:top">
   <div>
   <img src="@img" style="height:150px; width:100px" alt=""/>
   </div>
   <div>@ss</div>

   </div>        
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks..  Using this type of url my image is showing in browser But not in my project application whose view page codings are mention above. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use physical path to view image in your project.
Try to copy all image files in virtual directory and use relative path only.